# How do I flee the special attack from Golden scorpion knight?

Tags: saint-seiya-senki

I'm having trouble to beat the Golden Knight of Scorpion (Milo) on Saint Seiya Senki (Sanctuary Battle).

Is there any way to flee his *Scarlet Needle* special attack ?

[image: Milo of Scorpion]

[image: Yoga being hit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized it, there are 2 ways of escaping:

1. The difficult one: Use the 7th sense when he is ready to shot the Scarlat Needle, and run around until he shots. This approach spends cosmo, and is a little hard to do when you're low on resources;
2. The easy one: Just hold the block button when Milo prepares the Scarlat Needle. He will shot, and you will block normally. This approach does not spend cosmo, but knocks you out of defense mode, so you have to be prepared to run after you got hit, or else Milo can run toward you and beat the crap out of you.